# Drupal facet change layout

Tags: php, drupal, layout, facet, solr

Is there any way to change the layout of a facet?

I know you can create a file in the template dir named: block-apachesolr_search-[field].tpl.php

The problem I am having is that at this stage the html in the block variable has already been created.

Is there any way to change the html or just get the elements of the facet?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about faceted search module?

you could overwrite stuff by adding it in your template file or something simmilar, forinstance i had to add the "clear-block" to a div and did it this way:

`function themename_faceted_search_ui_facet_wrapper($env, $facet, $context, $content) {
  $classes = array(
    'faceted-search-facet', // Note: Tooltips rely on this class.
    'faceted-search-env-'. $env->name,
    'faceted-search-facet--'. check_plain($facet->get_key() .'--'. $facet->get_id()), // Note: Tooltips rely on this class.
    'faceted-search-facet-'. ($facet->is_active() && $context != 'related' ? 'active' : 'inactive'),
    'faceted-search-'. $context,
  );
  return ''. $content .''."\n";
}`

took a while to find the right function in the module file, but i dont know of any other way.

Comment: No. I am talking about the apachesolr search module -> http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr